# Get animation length - Unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I need to yield for the length of my animation that is in the base layer and named "TurnAround". It makes the character display an animation of them turning around. How do I get this turnaround? Then How do I get the time length?

Is Turnaround an AnimationState? Is it an AnimationStateInfo? It is one of the animations in Animator with transitions.

I have `anim = GetComponent<Animator>();` to get the Animator. I'm looking at `turnAround = anim.getCurrentAnimatorStateInfo` but don't think that is quite right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is under [`AnimationClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AnimationClip-length.html).

Get it calling:

```
float length = gameObject.animation.clip.length;
```

**EDIT**

Since you are using an animator, you can do this:

```
Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

float length = animator.animation.clip.length;
```

[`Animator`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animator.html) inherits `Animation`, you can call of `Animation`'s members.

**EDIT 2**

Here is the final way that will definitely work:

```
Animation turnBack; //assign in inspector

...

float length = turnBack.clip.length;
```

`turnBack` goes at the top so it is a global variable, then you assign the animation to it in the unity editor (inspector). You can also do this with an array of animations and reference them by their index

```
Animation[] animations = new Animation[max];

float length = animations[index].clip.length;
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I specify the TurnAround animation?

Comment: The sprite doesn't have an animation. It has an animator that has animations that do work. Should I just it an animation?

Comment: @user3164083 Check edits, and the animation "TurnAround" is an object of type `Animation`, so `animation` is the specific animation "TurnAround"

Comment: So, `float length = anim.TurnAround.clip.length;`??

Comment: MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "doc" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "doc". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached

Comment: @user3164083 call `anim.animation["name"].clip.length `

Comment: Yes thanks. I got the error above. My sprite has an Animator, which has animations transitioning in the Animator. This is the only way I have been taught by tutorials.

Comment: I don't really understand sorry. I went to add an animation to my sprite. I think that's what you meant by "Animation turnBack; //assign in inspector". Then dragged my animation into it, and it said I need to mark as legacy. I sort of think even doing that is too much work, and can get messy, because I have other animations that I want to reference in the code aswell

Comment: Add an animation by clicking Add Component***. Not sure I should have to do that because it is already in the animator, and I would have to add every single one that I was to reference in code. Just seems weird.

Comment: @user3164083 What I mean by assign in inspector is the script component will display public variables that you can modify in the editor. Go to the script component, then where it says "Turn Back : none", assign an animation to it by clicking on the option button and select tthe animation you want

Comment: `float length = GetComponent<Animator> ().GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0)[0].clip.length`